# No data is inserted in MDB after executing insert query

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

When I try to insert some data in an MS Access DB, the data is not inserted. Is something missing in my code?

This is the code

```
public void Toevoegen(
        int nummer, string voornaam, string achternaam, 
        string gsm, string nationaliteit, string adres, 
        DateTime geboorteDatum, string geboortePlaats, DateTime inschrijvingsDatum, 
        string sporten, int postCode, string gemeente, string klasse,
        Boolean competitie, string ziektes, string email)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = @"INSERT INTO Lid "
                + "VALUES ("
                + "@Lid_ID, "
                + "@Lid_VoorNaam, "
                + "@Lid_AchterNaam, "
                + "@Lid_Email, "
                + "@Lid_GeboorteDatum, "
                + "@Lid_InschrijvingsDatum, "
                + "@Lid_Nationaliteit, "
                + "@Lid_GeboortePlaats, "
                + "@Lid_Adres, "
                + "@Lid_PostCode, "
                + "@Lid_Gemeente, "
                + "@Lid_GSM, "
                + "@Lid_BeoefendeSporten, "
                + "@Lid_Competitie, "
                + "@Lid_KickKlasse, "
                + "@Lid_Ziektes)";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_ID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = nummer;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_VoorNaam", OleDbType.Char).Value = voornaam;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_Achternaam", OleDbType.Char).Value = achternaam;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_Email", OleDbType.Char).Value = email;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_GeboorteDatum", OleDbType.Date).Value = geboorteDatum;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_InschrijvingsDatum", OleDbType.Date).Value = inschrijvingsDatum;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_Nationaliteit", OleDbType.Char).Value = nationaliteit;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_GeboortePlaats", OleDbType.Char).Value = geboortePlaats;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_Adres", OleDbType.Char).Value = adres;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_PostCode", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = postCode;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_Gemeente", OleDbType.Char).Value = gemeente;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_GSM", OleDbType.Char).Value = gsm;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_BeoefendeSporten", OleDbType.Char).Value = sporten;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_Competitie", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = competitie;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_KickKlasse", OleDbType.Char).Value = klasse;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Lid_Ziektes", OleDbType.Char).Value = ziektes;
            conn.executeInsertQuery(command);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }
```

--

```
public bool executeInsertQuery(OleDbCommand _command)
    {
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        try
        {
            myCommand.Connection = openConnection();
            //myCommand.CommandText = _query;
            //myCommand.Parameters.AddRange(dbParameter);
            myAdapter.InsertCommand = _command;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OleDbException e)
        {
            Console.Write("Error - Connection.executeInsertQuery - Query: " 
                + _command.CommandText + " \nException: \n" + e.StackTrace.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem will be here:

```
myAdapter.InsertCommand = _command;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You assign command to `myAdapter` but then execute `myCommand` which is empty.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OleDb, but assigning _command to myCommand and then execute the query will work?

Comment: that's exactly what I did, but the data isn't inserted :s

Comment: Have you checked your connection? Are you working with the right datasource?

Comment: I am not sure if I was of any help, what was the problem actually?

Comment: You gave me the idea that maybe myParameter was wrong. I discovered that the parameters were wrong. I only initialized one, and assign the command to it. I will post the solution and the code, if you want.